# Windows Taskbar hangs since WiFi Extender set up

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, router, taskbar

*(This question was first posted on Stack Overflow, but recommended to ask here. So I do it).*

I have recently suffered from an annoying Windows problem: **Windows Taskbar hangs occasionally at an unknown time**. Consequently, Taskbar icons (including Start and Windows key) are no more clickable.

I have five computers (one Mac and four running Windows 10) connecting to my home WiFi network including a router (also Access Point) and a TP-Link WiFi Extender/Repeater. The problem is found on four Windows computers only.

I notice the problem has been there since I set up and connected the devices to the WiFi Extender/Repeater.

What I have tried:

1. Make sure the Extender is set up as recommended by the manufacturer.
2. Make sure the Extender is in Repeater Mode.
3. Assign a manual IP address for each device/computer in the network.
4. Keep the Mac connected to the extending network. Connect all four Windows PCs to the host network.
5. Disable and enable the WiFi network adapter.
6. Renew DHCP from the command line (Win + X fails, using Task Manager to browse to Systems32 for **cmd**).
7. Restart the computers.

But none of these helps to fix the problem.

I *partly* fix the problem by the following *workarounds*.

1. End and start Windows Explorer from Task Manager.
2. Use Ctrl + Alt + Del to turn off or change the current WiFi connection.
3. Unplug and replug the Extender.

It is noted that each of these workarounds may work this time or may not work other time. Sometimes, I have to combine more than one way to fix the problem.

So, **What is really this problem? How can it be permanently fixed?**

Help highly appreciated.

Comment: You are probably targeting the wrong problem.  The behavior you describe is most likely caused by a third party shell extension that relies on the network to function properly.  I am guessing that you are repeatedly installing the same third party crap on all of these machines.  The explorer works just fine without even having internet connectivity so the only thing that makes sense is a third party tool that is mirrored on all of these devices.

Comment: Your comment may be a good hint for me. I'm thinking of any third-party extension that is installed on all four Windows PCs.

Comment: Apart from my own PC, which is installed with a munber of "advanced" applications, all other PCs are just installed with quite basic applications like Office 365, Chrome, Zoom, Teams... No browser add-ons are allowed. One PC (phablet) has Office 365 and Chrome only. The only thing that all four PCs share is my Wallpaper collection of about 50 images (with some 4k ones). I have suspected the wallpapers, and disabled Background slideshow, set  Windows default images or solid color, but the problem is still there.